# how to find three records with highest average?

Tags: t-sql

I have to find highest average for 3 shipped countries:

```
select shipcountry, AVG(freight) as "avgfreight" 
from sales.orders  where year(shippeddate)=2007  
group by shipcountry  
order by 2 desc
```

I am not able to use `top` command to find top 3 averages. any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're not able to use the TOP command? Is this homework? If so, you should state so.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using a subquery:

```
select top 3 shipcountry, avgfreight
from (
   select shipcountry, avg(freight) avgfreight
   from sales.orders
   where year(shppeddate) = 2007
   group by shipcountry
) t
order by avgfreight desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `CTE`

```
;With cte as (
   select shipcountry, AVG(freight) avgfreight
   from sales.orders  
   where year(shippeddate)=2007  
   group by shipcountry  
)
select top(3) shipcountry, avgfreight
from cte
order by avgfreight desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set rowcount 3

select shipcountry, AVG(freight) as "avgfreight"
from sales.orders where year(shippeddate)=2007
group by shipcountry
order by 2 desc
```

This will limit the number of rows returned (for every query executed on that connection).

If you're re-using the connection (issuing more statements etc) you'll want to reset rowcount when you're done.

e.g.

```
set rowcount 3

select shipcountry, AVG(freight) as "avgfreight"
from sales.orders where year(shippeddate)=2007
group by shipcountry
order by 2 desc

set rowcount 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 3 shipcountry, AVG(freight) as "avgfreight" 
from sales.orders
where year(shippeddate)=2007
group by shipcountry  
order by AVG(freight) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @sales_orders table 
(
    shipcountry varchar(max),
    freight int,
    shippeddate datetime
)

insert into @sales_orders values 
('India', '2000', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('India', '2100', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('India', '2500', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('SriLanka', '1000', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('SriLanka', '1500', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('SriLanka', '1200', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('China', '500', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('China', '1000', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('China', '900', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('USA', '100', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('USA', '200', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate())),
('USA', '600', dateadd(yy,-6, getutcdate()))


;with cte
as
(
select shipcountry, AVG(freight) as avgfreight
from @sales_orders  where year(shippeddate)=2007  
group by shipcountry 
)
select top 3 avgfreight,shipcountry from cte order by avgfreight desc
```